# Importing local files in `jest.config.js` file

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In my `jest.config.js` file, I need to populate `globals` property. For populating the `globals` property I need to require local modules, as shown below:

```
const path = require('path')
const server = require('./server/cfg')

module.exports = {
    rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname),
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'js',
        'json',
        'vue',
        'ts'
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
    },
    transform: {
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest",
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.ts$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest"
    },
    testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    snapshotSerializers: [
        "jest-serializer-vue"
    ],
    setupFiles: [
      "<rootDir>/globals.js"
    ],
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    globals: {
        server: {
            server
        }
    }
}
```

Whit this configuration, I get the following error:

`Error: Cannot find module './server/cfg'`

This is my folder structure

```
server/
   cfg.ts
src/
jest.config.js
webpack.config.js
```

However, I can `require` node's built-in modules. I'm not able to figure out why it is happening. Any ideas on how I can overcome this?

Comment: try changing `rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname)` to `rootDir: './'` in jest config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jest is initiated by `node`, not `ts-node` and it's not able to resolve the `.ts` file by default.

Probably adding [setupFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) will help you.

**`jest.config.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
  // ... your config
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "<rootDir>/environmentWithServer.ts`
  ]
}
```

**`environmentWithServer.ts`**

```js
global.server = require('./server/cfg');
```

Comment: Thanks  Teneff, i was able to solve the problem. I also needed to add `tsconfig.json` file as the sibling to `jest.config.js` file.